# Nodename nor servname provided, or not known Java

Tags: java

Recently I tried running my Java project and whenever I run it and open it up to the server address I am getting:

```
     Unable to determine host name
java.net.UnknownHostException: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: (USERNAME): nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

where USERNAME is my username. I believe it has something to do with my /etc/hosts file. I have tried modifying that changing it to:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

And it is still getting the same error every time that I cannot find the sever. I have been stuck on this for a while, mostly time spent modifying the hosts file, but no luck. Any ideas as to how I can get this resolved?

I have also tried deleting my project and re-clone it, and it is still getting the same error.

Ultimately, I think it has something to do with not being able to connect with the host.

Comment: The hosts file has nothing to do with it. You should add the source that produces the error to your question, and the data you are passing to it for the host name.

Comment: This blog post helped me to resolve this issue:
https://crunchify.com/getting-java-net-unknownhostexception-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-error-on-mac-os-x-update-your-privateetchosts-file/

Comment: Why is this voted up? There is no code provided, so all we know is that an error happened, somehow, on a system with no details provided (JDK version or operating system). Also, I looked at the link above (crunchify), and I'm unable to reproduce any problems on macOS 12.4 with OpenJDK 17 – calling `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()` works fine without editing `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered the same issue. There might be several issues, causing this. Below are a few that are most probable:

1. URL and Hostname -- if we have any typos in the URL
2. DNS Resolution -- DNS resolution fails for the hostname you are trying to reach, You can try pinging the hostname from your terminal to see if it resolves.
3. Proxy Configuration -- if you are trying to hit any API or URL that is protected, your proxy configuration must be set correctly.

For me, the issue was proxy configuration, because the URL I was trying to hit through my code was Org protected, and a VPN was required to access it so, I added the code to set it and then resolved the host IP without any issue.

sample code to set proxy using `java.net`:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.example.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

I added proxy for both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`

```
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "2006");

        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","2006");
```

Comment: For me, it was the first scenario