# JDBC Driver error when connecting to Snowflake through DataGrip

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jdbc-odbc

Sorry to reach out, I searched for an answer but I didn't see anything relating to my specific issue, sorry if I missed it.
I used to connect fine to Snowflake using Datagrip with JDBC driver 3.13.5.
Yesterday, in order to be able to use Snowflake with Tableau, I installed the ODBC driver, as well as ODBC Manager. Since, then, impossible for me to connect using Datagrip, I get the following error message :

```
JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: <URL>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

The connection string is: jdbc:snowflake://:443 and used to work fine until yesterday.
I tried updating to 3.13.7 (last version), but same issue.
Does anybody have an idea of what I did wrong and what to do?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help and support, have a great day!
Nicolas

Comment: Hi - that’s obviously not a valid connection string, there’s no url in it for a start. Please update your question with the actual connection string (masking any information that would identify your account/user/password/etc)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @NickW. I thought I had written it properly but the obfuscated part disappeared. Here it is: jdbc:snowflake://https://XXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024527/nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-java

Comment: From that above post try the blog post for answer/info: https://crunchify.com/getting-java-net-unknownhostexception-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-error-on-mac-os-x-update-your-privateetchosts-file/